# PostgreSQL Dynamic query to insert a json string(text) to table(text) by 2 param in function

Tags: json, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I'm having a problem when calling a function with 2 parameters as text to make it a dynamic SQL. The problem is the first param has quote mark ' so my dynamic query is failing. Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "dbo"."sp_insertbulk"("tablename" text, "jsonitem" text)
RETURNS SETOF "pg_catalog"."void" AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE ('INSERT INTO '|| $1 ||' SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::'|| $1 ||','''|| $2 ||'''::json)');
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

I also try using Format():

```
  EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::%I , %I::json)',$1,$1,$2);
```

but it will make my jsonitem param unreadable

```
 ({""ShortName"":""abc"",""Name"":""abc"",""Slogan"":""abc"" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `quote_ident($1)` or `%I` for the column name and `quote_nullable($1)` or `%L` for values.

See [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in the Postgres docs.